# Umbraco - Getting Textstring value

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I'm trying to get the value of a text string of page, assign a url to it, and then display the result on a different page using xslt. I'm not sure how to get the value of the textstring.

Here is my macro:

```
    <!-- Input the related links property alias here -->
    <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="/macro/fieldName"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:if test="$fieldName != ''">
            <!-- The fun starts here -->

                        <xsl:element name="a">
                            <xsl:if test="./new-window[. = 'True']">
                                <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:if>

                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="/myUrl.aspx"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>

                            <xsl:value-of select="./@title"/>
                        </xsl:element>

        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! `select="$parent/*[name() = $fieldName]`